# Get contact phone number from payment using PayPal REST API

Tags: rest, paypal

I'm using PayPal REST API to get the details of an authorized payment. Is it somehow possible to get also the contact phone number assigned to the payment?

The users are required to fill in their phone number. If I open a transaction's details in the PayPal website, the phone number is there. When using GET /v1/payments/payment/ the payer_info doesn't includes it.

Comment: Which types of payments are you using -- PayPal or credit card payments?

Comment: Credit card payments are not available in my country, so PayPal.